# Trying to Convert Two Things inside on function

Tags: javascript, function

- I am trying to build a unit converter for Length, Volume and Mass
- I am trying to get for example length to meter && meter to length to display on the same line inside my website.

This is my current code, but I am not sure what I am trying to complete can be done with how I have my code, I have been all over google and continuing to search:

```
let inputEl = document.getElementById("input")
let lengthEl = document.getElementById("length-el")
let volumeEl = document.getElementById('volume-el')
let massEl = document.getElementById('mass-el')

const meterToFeet = 3.281
const feetToMeter = 0.305
const literToGallon =  0.264
const kiloToPound =  2.204

//For the Length Converter//
convertBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let baseValue = inputEl.value
    
    lengthEl.textContent = `${baseValue} Meter = ${baseValue * meterToFeet.toFixed(3)} Feet` 
})
```

I was trying to add this inside the function, but keep getting errors. I then attempted to do a standalone function for Feet to Meter but this is the code:

`` lengthElEl.textContent = `${baseValue} Feet = ${baseValue * feetToMeter.toFixed(3)} Meter ``

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for reading even if you don't respond : )

Comment: Do you want two input values side by side so you could calculate them vice versa?

Comment: Yeah, for example I want it to show this:

```0 Meters = 0.000 feet | 0 Feet = 0.000 meters``` 

But run the calculations on the the same line. I did thing about adding two sections in HTML for the two calculations (if that makes sense).

Thanks for the comment and reading!

Comment: I may have solved it by doing this:

```${baseValue} Meter = ${baseValue * meterToFeet.toFixed(3)} Feet || Feet = ${baseValue * feetToMeter.toFixed(3)} Meter ```